# viewDidAppear() and viewDidLoad() not called

Tags: ios, swift

Overriding functions `viewDidAppear` and `viewDidLoad` doesn't seem to work. I tested by printing to the console, nothing comes out. The rest of the function body doesn't execute either.

I made sure the method signature is `override func viewDidLoad()`.

The View Controller class is not directly the subclass of the `UITableViewController` class.

There is a class:

```
class EntityVC<E: Entity>: UITableViewController {
    var dataRetriever: DataRetriever<E>!
    var cachedEntities: CachedEntities<E>!
    var entityName: String!

//Other functions...
```

then this View Controller class extends to it:

```
class StallTableVC: EntityVC<Stall>, UISearchBarDelegate {
```

To clarify, `StallTableVC` is what the storyboard is hooked to, NOT `EntityVC`.

Would that have something to do with it? I realize this is also the reason why in the storyboard, the View Controller class does not appear in the list of suggestions, however I made sure it was selected.

Comment: I did this, although Xcode complained that the class couldn't be visible to objective C as it is a generic class subclass.

Comment: Could this be an issue with reaching the scene (ignoring the fact that it's generics)? What happens if you assign another class to it? A plain `UIViewController` for instance

Comment: If I replaced the generic superclass with a simple `UITableViewController`, then yes, it would be visible to the storyboard.

Comment: Thanks. This solves it.